# Can cursor change to pointer be delayed using CSS3 animation?

Tags: html, css

I have an image that (when hovered over) enlarges (using CSS animation).
The image is also a link to another page.

So if the cursor goes to 'pointer' immediately the visitor hovers - it will look like it's just an effect of the animation - and they may not realise it's a hyperlink.

(Now that it's 2014) is there an easy way with e.g. 'transition-delay' to delay the cursor-change until the animation is over?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You may use Javascript to detect the `transitionend` event that is fired when your hover transition ends.

[**MDN transitionend docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) states:

> The transitionend event is fired when a CSS transition has completed.

So, bind a listener to the element, and change the cursor accordingly:

```
var element = document.getElementById("myDiv");
element.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {
    element.style.cursor = "pointer";
}, false);
```

Comment: This method is much more reliable

Comment: If the only CSS property you want to transition is the `cursor`, you must use a dummy transition property and value, something that does nothing visually.  If your transition property is `cursor`, it will behave as in the answer below this one, by switching to the new cursor half-way through the transition time, not at `transitionend`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there is a way to do it with pure CSS, this solution incorporates jQuery.

Set your cursor type in CSS

```
#image {
    cursor: default; //default is the "arrow"
}
```

Then use jQuery to modify image on hover and change the pointer when the animation is complete.

```
$("#image").hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        "width": 200,
        "height": 200,
     }, 1500 );   
     setTimeout(pointer, 1500);
});

function pointer() {
    $("#image").css('cursor', 'pointer'); //pointer is the "hand"
}
```

#### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8ppxroLm/3/)

Comment: Good solution! I would recommend putting the $("#image").css('cursor', 'pointer'); (without the timeout) in the [complete] param (http://api.jquery.com/animate/) of the animate() and possible reversing the animation/cursor in the handlerOut param (http://api.jquery.com/hover/) of hover. Revised your fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/8ppxroLm/4/

Comment: @DonBoots Cool thanks for the advice, one thing to note though is that if the user hovers and unhovers several times in your fiddle they'll have to wait for the animation to complete which could take a while

Answer (score 1):

you can write pure CSS instead using JavaScript
CSS:

```
#image{
     cursor: default;
     transition: cursor 3s linear ;
}
#image:hover{
     cursor: pointer;
}
```

**actually CSS transitions are made for numeric styles**
but when you use them to change something like cursor (or text-align,display,...) it will suddenly change that property to value you wrote , at the middle of duration
so if you set for example 3 seconds time to do that it will change your property correctly on 1.5seconds

Comment: Interesting. But it's generally a bad practice to rely on unintended side-effects like this. Since this behavior isn't specified in the spec, browsers may one day change their implementation and your code will break.

Comment: This sure is a tempting approach. Regardless of whether I implement it or not, the answer provides useful information about how things are actually implemented in browsers.  For that I upvote it.

Comment: This no longer works in chrome -  you can make use of animation key-frames though to set the cursor at specific points.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I used jQuery and a setTimeout to apply a css class after 8ms.

JavaScript:

```
  var timeoutRef; 
  var mySpan = $("span");
    
  mySpan.on("mouseover", function () {
      timeoutRef = setTimeout(function () {
        mySpan.addClass("help");
      }, 800);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function () {
      clearTimeout(timeoutRef);
      mySpan.removeClass("help");
    });
```

Then CSS class:

```
span.help {
  cursor: help;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this. (I wanted to create ilusion of download something :) ).

Regarding you question: problem with examples talking about based on tansition on hover changing cursor are not proper, because cursor unlike others parameters have no intermediate forms. So the transition can be only like 1/0. One form of cursor or another. Nothing beetwen. Thats why there is no way to transform cursor itself.

BUT !

You can transform element having different declarations of cursor form. And this it the mistery of my solution. Try my example: target element (span "TESTER" in my example) is going to have cursor "wait" for a while on hover, and after that the cursor is going to change to pointer. This simulates "downloading" :)

The solution is that :after pseudo class which on start has width 0px, on hover streches to expected with (covering all target element where cursor is in "wait" form), and there in :after object cursor form is declared as "pointer". And because it covers target element - the cursor changes.

Additionally in my exmple I show how to use transition to show info box (span "INFORMATION" in my example).

- :after content and background needs to be transparent to hide its existence.
- for test purposes you can add colors to see wahts is going on.
- checkout my comment in code, according content of :after.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.content{
    width: 300px;
    height: 22px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

span.switcher{
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: wait;
    background-color: red;
}

span.switcher:after{
    /*content of :after need to be at least long as its width. Changing the content changes the cursor*/
    content: "--------------------------------------";
    color: rgb(0 0 0 / 0%);
    /* color: black; */
    background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 0%);
    /* background-color: yellow; */
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    left: 50px;
    margin-top: -46px;
    height: 24px;
    width: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

span.switcher:hover:after{
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
    width: 200px;
}

span.information{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 0px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    padding: 0px;
    
    background-color: lightblue;
    font-size: 0px;
    
    transition: 0.3s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

span.switcher:hover span.information{
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 200px;
    
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: calc(50% - 100px);

    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <span class="switcher">
            TESTER
            <span class="information">
                INFORMATION
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```