# CSS - Cursor Transition

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to animate with a CSS transition the status of the cursor?

I've tried with this code but it is not working.

```css
.test {
  cursor: default;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.test:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-transition: cursor 500ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: cursor 500ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: cursor 500ms ease-in-out;
  transition: cursor 500ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: What do you expect / want to happen? How would you define a cursor that is "halfway between `default` and `pointer`"?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol No, I mean a smooth transition, like you can do with opacity or other CSS properties

Comment: Why do you want to change the cursor? - The transitions only animate items on the page, that is what CSS is for. To do that to the cursor you might need to try something like javascript. but i wouldnt really recommend it

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for your reply

Comment: @Alessio Yes, sure, a smooth transition, but a smooth transition has to pass through the halfway point, doesn't it? So what would it look like at that moment? ;)

Comment: Also with a lot of mobile users wont even know that you have done this as they dont have a cursor.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Good point of view, I didn't think about it :)

Comment: This might lead you down the right sort of path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551277/using-external-images-for-css-custom-cursors

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25794864/can-cursor-change-to-pointer-be-delayed-using-css3-animation/78052479#78052479

As I say in my post above: "...problem with examples talking about based on tansition on hover changing cursor are not proper, because cursor unlike others parameters have no intermediate forms. So the transition can be only like 1/0. One form of cursor or another. Nothing beetwen. Thats why there is no way to transform cursor itself."

So I show the working solution using css only, giving requested effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is not possible with CSS alone. Transition only works on **animatable properties**; whereas `cursor` does not appear. For a full list of animatable props, please check [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#properties-from-css-).

Please notice you may also put `.gif` for the .cursor element; bare in mind there are certain size restrictions that apply accordingly on different browsers.

Comment: And not all browsers support GIF as a cursor format. You should also have a ANI cursor file as an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

**`Cursor`** is not an animatable property and it would be kind of weird if it were to be honest. If you want to create an animation I would suggest creating a **`GIF`** that would start as **`default`** and end as **`pointer`**.

Then you can use that **`GIF`** as shown:

```
.test:hover {
    cursor: url("your-image.gif"), auto;
}
```

Comment: This could be a nice solution, I will try it!

Comment: Keep in mind though that different people have different pointers. Sure, many might have the default Windows set, but not everyone is on Windows for a start. So if you go for something like this, you will need to override *all* cursors with your own theme.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol True! :\

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol is right. Unless you intend to override all cursors it's not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You can, by specifying a url to it in CSS:

```
.test{
    cursor:default;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}

.test:hover{        
    cursor:url(smiley.gif),url(myBall.cur),auto;
}
```