# Hover state of custom cursor

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I wanna built a custom cursor effect like [this one](https://www.alexvanzijl.nl/).

My solution includes a `<div>` element that follows the cursor using the `onmousemove` event.

Which is the proper way to **handle hover state** (want to change the cursor's appearance), when the cursor is inside specific elements?

Comment: Proper way is to apply style to your cursor in your css: Please Refer - https://www.w3docs.com/tools/code-editor/2404

Comment: You can check this, it is probably a solution for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281666/animate-custom-cursor-when-hovering-on-a-link

Comment: @HugoS I wanted to run away from adding a custom function to each hoverable element, but it seems the only valid solution. Thanks for the reference answer anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave`

```html
<div>
  <div id='cursor'></div>
  <div onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}>Hover</div>
</div>
```

```js
var cursorElement = document.getElementById('cursor');
function onMouseEnter(){
  cursorElement.classList.add('hovered');
}
function onMouseLeave(){
  cursorElement.classList.remove('hovered'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently hovered element can be obtained from event target of mousemove event

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
        let current target = e.target
    }
)
```